# How to access Environment Variables in Django with Django Environ?

Tags: python, django

I'm a Node developer but I need to create a Django app (i'm totally beginner in Django).
I need to read some data from an API but ofc, I shouldn't hardcode the API url.

So having **API_BASE_URL=api.domain.com** in my **.env** file, in Node I would access the variables in my functions this way:

```js
import ('dotenv/config');
import axios from 'axios';

baseUrl = process.env.API_BASE_URL;

function getApiData() {
    return axios.get(baseUrl);
}
```

So how would be the Python/Django version of it?

Saying I have the function bellow:

```py
import ???

def get_api_data():
    url = ????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import environ

# reading .env file
environ.Env.read_env()

def get_api_data():
    url = env('API_BASE_URL')
```

Comment: what about if variables are not in .env, but in environment? Like on heroku.

Comment: @cikatomo You can use something like this: `os.environ['API_BASE_URL']` according to the official documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a .env file saved in the same directory as your manage.py file.

You can then go to settings.py and do:

```
from decouple import config

API_BASE_URL = config('API_BASE_URL')
```

Assuming your .env file looks like:

```
API_BASE_URL='some.url'
```

Comment: For this, I think that he has to install the python-decouple package